Jesus' ministry was only 1 year?
How would you respond to the arguments listed on this website:
https://trumpet-call.org/2016/01/11/ministry-of-jesus-christ-on-earth-was-only-one-year/

could you condense the points and include them in the question? SO does not have control over the third party website, and its better to include content not just links to the content

The link you provide is to a very muddled article which is not laid out in sufficient orderliness to prove the matter one way or another. The article also makes assumptions 'could very well be'. The author appears to be asserting an interpretation of Isaiah which requires a literal prophecy of timing, There are many far more detailed and convincing timelines which indicate three, or more, years.

Welcome to Christianity! Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. To find out what we look for in well-researched question, please take our tour: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour


OP From the Link:  the gospel of John is not strictly in chronological order and this Passover could very well be the final Passover mentioned in other gospels.

It may be, however, that John is in chronological order and the others are not.
Re Isa 61:1-2, if this was a literal year, as the link suggests, then this obviously would have also happened on a Passover.  So, there's at least two.
The link ignores Daniel's prophecy of being cut of in the middle of 7 years; that is, at 3 1/2 years.
3 1/2 years from Tabernacles birth/birthday and baptism to Passover after the 3 1/2 years.
'Nuff said.

John's gospel is not chronological. And consider how he jumps straight from the pre-existence (as the Word) to John the Baptist's ministry. He misses other events out as well, for the purpose of his account is to prove "Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that believing ye might have life through his name" Jn.20:31. He deals with the 7 signs in Jesus' ministry, but not chronological order. A good answer.
